# How to convert JMSBytesMessage to TextMessage in Java

Tags: java, jms

I'm build some MQ Queue Connection, I need to cast message queue to JMS Textmessage from `queueReceiver.Receivenowait()`.

Because `queueReceiver.Receivenowait()` format is Byte, I need convert it to Textmessage for break message into array List.

I already do this using:

```
queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(ringQueue);
```

To get Bytemessage, I need to convert to JMS text message:

```
List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (loop) {
   TextMessage msgResponse = (TextMessage) bytesMessage;
   if (msgResponse.getText() == null) {
      loop = false;
   } else {
      message = msgResponse.getText();
      outputList.add(message);
      msgResponse.acknowledge();
   }
}
```

And I've got this error code:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.jms.JMSBytesMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you don't really want to convert the `BytesMessage` to a `TextMessage`, but simply want to convert the byte array in the `BytesMessage` to a `String`. If that's true, then you can use code like this:

```java
List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (loop) {
   if (bytesMessage instanceof BytesMessage) {
      BytesMessage msgResponse = (BytesMessage) bytesMessage;
      if (msgResponse.getBodyLength() == 0) {
         loop = false;
      } else {
         byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) msgResponse.getBodyLength()];
         msgResponse.readBytes(bytes);
         outputList.add(new String(bytes));
         msgResponse.acknowledge();
      }
   }
}
```

Of course, `bytesMessage` will need to be a different message every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API docs for [BytesMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html#readUTF()) might reveal a possible way to do that.  Beyond that simply reading the bytes from the message and using `new String(bytes, charset)` is an option.

It is generally a good idea to check the incoming message to determine if the type matches your expectations.

```
if (message instanceof TextMessage) ...
```

That way you can handle the negative case appropriately.